# VB.NET: Populating ComboBox Using MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I am trying to populate a Combobox from a MySQL database; but I don't get anything.
Below is the code.

Table: Class

Columns: Code, State

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Class WHERE State= Not Started"
DBCmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlstr, DBConn)
DBDR = DBCmd.ExecuteReader
While (DBDR.Read())
CB_Class.Items.Add(DBDR("Code"))
End While
DBCmd.Dispose()
DBDR.Close()
```

I believe the result is wrong, because there are at least 2 records with their state values set as "Not Started". What is wrong? Is there anything wrong with the way I've written "State= Not Started" ?

Comment: The program works fine until it reaches DBDR = DBCmd.ExecuteReader. It doesn't execute any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command text doesn't seems correct. It lacks the single quote around the string to search

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Class WHERE State='Not Started'"
                                          ^           ^
```

If `State` is a string field then every search over it should be enclosed in single quotes.
Beware of the potential problems when the string to search contains a single quote.

In this simple case you could use directly the string constant, but if you render your search dynamic with user input then you should use parametrized queries.